# how to insert a form value by ajax in php...any example..?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have been asked to insert a form  value by Ajax in PHP and I am puzzled a looking for a good example of it and any good example site URL?

I am using this code:

```
var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone;  
//alert (dataString);return false;  
$.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "bin/process.php",  
  data: dataString,  
  success: function() {  
    $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");  
    $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")  
    .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")  
    .hide()  
    .fadeIn(1500, function() {  
      $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");  
    });  
  }  
});  
return false;
```

Comment: `I have been asked to insert a form value by Ajax in PHP` - asked by whom? Your teacher?

Comment: @asprin No asked by my gf

Comment: insert it where ? into database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link explains how to use AJAX with PHP to send the form input as an email:
http://www.devblog.co/easy-jquery-ajax-php-contact-form/

If you need to input the values into a mysql database,
- create the table in mysql
- in the php code, connect to the mysql database
- instead of sending the values to an email, run insert statements on the open mysql connection (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)
 - close the connection

Answer (score 0):

I do not know more about JavaScript but you may use it simply

```
function formSubmit(id1,id2,id3){ //<input type="text" id="username" ...
if(id1 == null || id2 == null || id3 == null){
    alert('Kindly fill Form properly');
    return false;
}else{
    var usr = document.getElementsByID(id1).value;
    var eml = document.getElementsByID(id2).value;
    var mbl = document.getElementsByID(id3).value;
    var dataString = 'name='+ usr + '&email=' + eml + '&phone=' + mbl;
    var url = 'bin/process.php?'+ dataString;
    $.get(url, function(data){
        if(data == 'exists'){
            //if data exists DO SOMETHING HERE
            return false;
        }else{
            alert('Form stored successfully');
            //Or use your own script
            return true;
        }
    });
}

}
```

Wish you will get some hints.